# Developer tools: Match for Site url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, developer-tools

I am using Dev tools with Google chrome and need to find out is the site url contains a specific string.
I am able to get *Url_Str* correctly, although when I run the match command it always returns a *"match found"*.
How do I fix this?

```html
let Url_Str = ___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].B.S.baseURI;
if (Url_Str.match(/*myconstant*/)) {"match found";}
```

Also is there a **Alternate way to get the site url** instead of using grecaptcha_cfg?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working. Thanks to Qasim @ https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/developer-tools-match-for-site-url/502817

```html
let Url_Str = window.location.href;
let a = 0
if(/myconstant.com/.test(Url_Str) === true) {a = 1;}
```